# Function spaces $L^p$ and $C^k$ inclusion?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Are there any inclusions in terms of set-theory (or estimates for corresponding norms) for $L^p$ and $C^k$ function spaces?

So, is there any $p, k$ so that $L^p  \subset  C^k$ or $C^k  \subset  L^p$ ?

Comment: On a finite measure space, continuous functions (and thus $k$ times continuously differentiable functions) are contained in $L^p$ fairly trivially (modulo issues regarding $L^p$ being made up of equivalence classes of functions, but this is easily addressed by thinking of the equivalence class related to the $C^k$ function). That said, the other inclusion doesn't quite make sense in general for the same reason. There are settings where $L^p$ functions can be defined pointwise (i.e. the classes have only one element) or even deal directly with derivatives, see Bargmann space and Sobolev space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

First, you have the problem that $L^p$ is defined as a set of equivalence classes, which $C^{k}$ is not (as @Cameron Williams) pointed out.

Moreover, $f(x)=x$ is in $C^k$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, but not in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Finally, $f(x)=1\{x=0\}$ is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, but not $C^k$.

Comment: These are decent examples to demonstrate that no inclusions hold